# PHPExcel - charts visible in LibreOffice but not in excel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have the next code for PHPExcel. I want to save an individual sheet in a different file. The original file contains charts:

```
 $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
 $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly('My Sheet');
 $objReader->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
 $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($excelFile);
 $objWriter= PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
 $objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
 $objWriter->save('myFile.xlsx');
```

The excel file is generated properly and the charts are visible through Libre Office. However in MS Excel I get this error when I open the file:

```
Removed Part: /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml part.  (Drawing shape)
```

And the charts are not shown.
Any clue?